# Nightwatch.js how to access secure site?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, nightwatch.js

selenium version: 3.8.1
chromedriver:latest
nightwatch:latest

Trying to login to a secure site like this:

```
browser
.url('https://mydomain\myuser:mypassword@securesite')
.waitForElementVisible('body')
.end();
```

Unfortunately no luck with this code: My credentials are not populated in the popup. How can I authenticate to this https-site? I attached a sample of the popup that appears. How can I login with a user through my testscript?Would this work in protractor. I attached an image of the login that pops up. [image]

Answer (score -1):

Try like that (of course use your locators instead):

```
browser
.url("http://yoursite")
.waitForElementVisible('body')
.setValue('input[name=UserName]', 'user')
.setValue('input[name=Password]', 'pass')
.click('#Login')
```